# How can I return temporary columns in linq query : from p in dbx.Perons select new {false,Id}?

Tags: linq

I want to write this query in linq but I can't:

```
select cast(0 as bit) as IsSelect , "test value" as ColumnTest, Id, LastName 
  from persons
```

I want temporary columns in my linq query. I've tried this but it is wrong:

```
  from p
  in dbContext.Persons
  select new { false, "test Value", p.Id, p.LastName }
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify property name for your static column:

```
select new {State= false, Name = "test value", ...}
```

Comment: tnx, but when i fill data in myDataGridView1.DataSource with this query, i cant edit the columns! I cant add new rows and i cant delete rows and I cant check the checkbox column!! what should i do?